# How to ensure a PostgreSQL Trigger will never cause a rollback?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

We wanted to monitor data of suspicious quality coming in in one of our tables and created a trigger to issue messages in case our quality checks failed.

Just to be sure, we desire to be absolutely impossible that this trigger could somehow cause the transaction to fail (and rollback), therefore impeding whatever the data change that was being checked.

Here's our current implementation:

```
create or replace function check_stuff()
returns trigger as
$$
declare
    original record;
    ...
begin
    original := new;
    ...
    if NEW.name ... then
        raise warning 'weird name detected';
    end if
    if NEW.address ... then
        raise warning 'weird address detected';
    end if
    ...
    return original;
exception
    when whatever then
        raise notice '% % % : % %', TG_NAME, TG_WHEN, TG_OP, SQLERRM, SQLSTATE; 
        return original;
end;
$$
language plpgsql

create trigger check_stuff_trigger
   after insert or update on important_table
   for each row execute procedure check_stuff();
```

Is it enough to capture all exceptions and backup the NEW row to some variable that is never again used except in the RETURN statements?

What set of rules can be agreed upon that will define a completely safe trigger?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to "save" the `new` record as long as you don't change it.

Comment: Your trigger is safe in the way you intend. The whole requirement seems somewhat weird, though: a) it shouldn't be the DBAs but the developers that write the trigger. Maybe their attitude comes from their database ignorance? b) complicated, error-prone business logic shouldn't be coded in a trigger anyway c) if they are worried about errors from a trigger, do they also feel that they shouldn't have primary and foreign keys on their data because that could lead to error messages from the database?